# Compress Image using Windows api and RLE

Tags: c++, windows, screenshot

I'm facing an issue when I want to get a screenshot compressed with RLE using windows api.
I'm using Qt/C++.

Here is my code :

```
void Screenshot::captureScreenCompressed() {
HWND hDesktopWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
HDC hDesktopDC = GetDC(hDesktopWnd);
HDC hCaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC);
HBITMAP hCaptureBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDesktopDC, _screenWidth, _screenHeight);
SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap);

BitBlt(hCaptureDC, 0, 0, _screenWidth, _screenHeight, hDesktopDC, 0,0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);

BITMAPINFO bmi = {0};
bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmi.bmiHeader);
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = _screenWidth;
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = - _screenHeight;
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RLE4;

if (GetDIBits(hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap, 0, _screenHeight, NULL, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS) == 0) {
    qDebug() << "Problem on Compression";
}

ReleaseDC(hDesktopWnd, hDesktopDC);
DeleteDC(hCaptureDC);
DeleteObject(hCaptureBitmap);
}
```

The final sizeImage is 0 and the getDiBits function returns 0.
I need some help thanks !

Comment: Why not just [QScreen::grabWindow()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#grabWindow) and then [QPixmap::save()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#save) ?

Comment: @VladimirBershov for some performance issue. Windows API is well more efficient than grabWindow. I'll call this function a lot.

Comment: Please note that dynamic objects are created and destroyed on every call

Comment: From [Bitmap Compression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183383.aspx): *"Windows supports formats for compressing bitmaps that define their colors with 8 or 4 bits-per-pixel."* - Yours is obviously using 32 bits-per-pixel. If you need efficient compression of 32bpp screenshots, use a PNG encoder (e.g. [PNG Codec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg430028.aspx)).

Comment: "Windows API is well more efficient than grabWindow." You might wish to have a peek in the implementation of `grabWindow`, then. I'm going to bet you didn't benchmark any of it and are optimizing things without any idea whether you improve anything at all.

Comment: @KubaOber I implemented both and Windows API well better than grabwindow. CPU usage was 13% with grabWindow over 5% with Windows API...

Comment: That's not benchmarking. That's comparing arbitrary numbers, guessing what they might relate to. Higher CPU usage could also mean, that an algorithm **is** more efficient, and doesn't stall as much as one with lower CPU usage. It could also be indicative of higher throughput, again, due to better efficiency.